# Navbar issue in Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a collapsable, floating navbar to the right hand side of the Jumbotron in my page. I am using Bootstrap 3.0.

My navbar collapses but the site name disappears when the navbar collapses. Also the navbar is pinned to the top of my screen rather than on the right hand side. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

```
<section>
<div class="navbar"> 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">DD Portfolio</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
    </nav>
 </section>


        <div class="jumbotron">
         <div class="container">
            <h1>Who Am I?</h1>
                <p>I am a student and content writer</p>
            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn More</a></p>
        </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to share css

Comment: You have an out-of-place DIV tag there. Also, you're missing a few DIVs and classes for a BS3 responsive menu.  I've put this into a JSFiddle for you, to help you get back on track: http://jsfiddle.net/BGDWb/1/

Comment: Where is the site name in your code?

Comment: My CSS is the default Bootstrap CSS. I haven't customised my navbar. Is there a way to float the navbar to the right-hand side within a Jumbotron?

Answer (score 0):

You should add site name to navbar-header, and also you have missed div closing tag. Here is complete code:

```
 <section>
    <div class="navbar">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">DD Portfolio</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</section>


<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Who Am I?</h1>
        <p>I am a student and content writer</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn More</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```